# There is a code involves the Delegate Up, I hope I understand it right

Tags: swift, class, delegates, initialization

Delegation is a new concept for me. To my understanding, it asks someone else to do some job for me. I then, delegate some tasks to him.

```
class Vehicle {
    var numberOfWheels = 0
    var description: String {
        return "\(numberOfWheels) wheel(s)"
    }
}

class Bicycle: Vehicle {
    override init() {
        super.init() //# Delegate up
        numberOfWheels = 2
    }
}
```

The code `super.init()` is a **delegate up** action in class initialization. The subclass initializer calls the initializer of the superclass first. The superclass' default initializer assigning the integer `0` to the variable `numberOfWheels`. This is Phase one initialization. After that, the overriding action of the subclass' initializer further customizes the variable by `numberOfWheels = 2`.

**Question** Is there any incorrectness of my understanding? and I hope the **delegate up** description I'm used here is correct.

Please correct any error and misunderstandings I have it here. Thanks

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_subclass_initializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are depicting here has nothing to do with delegation-pattern at all, it's the concept of inheritance. Your bicycle class is inheriting from Vehicle. Vehicle has already implemented some code, so instead of writing it again you can use the code of the super-class (the class that is inherited from). Your super-class doesn't have a defined initializer, therefore the super.init() wont even do anything. You should read about [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) and try to understand this concept better.

Here's what delegation does: You are right about the idea of delegation. It allows you to "outsource" some work to another class. This can be achieved with protocols. A delegate has to conform a delegation protocol to ensure that it has the methods you want to call on it. You are using protocols instead of inherited classes here, because you don't care about the implementation of the specific methods, you just want to tell your delegate to handle a situation, it's up to the delegate to know what to do.

Delegation is most commonly used in MVC applications for macOS and iOS. You can read more about delegation in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#Delegation). There are also dozens of tutorials [like this one](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1) on the internet that show how delegation works in practice.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation ")